# Alignment not coming correcting when browser resizing - responsive page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Bootstrap3` for my responsive page design here. I am adding a box inside the banner content with some text inside it as follows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <section id="slider">

    <ul class="rslides" id="modest-slider">

      <li class="slider-wrapper">

        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=slider1" alt="slider1" />
        </div>

        <div class="slider-caption container">
          <div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: auto; bottom: 126px; width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); height:130px;">
            <h1>Exclusively  New Concept!</h1>
            <p class="slider-description2">
              Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.slider-caption -->

      </li>
      <!-- /.slider-wrapper -->
      </ui>
  </section>
```

It is working fine in full screen. When I am resizing the browser the alignment is not working correctly. The box with content is not fit with the page. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: you're adding a fixed width: `width: 600px;` therefore it will not go below that width, therefore probably be larger than your mobile view

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, Ty buddy, How can I resolve this?I had even removed the width parameter also still not working. I am new to this, please help

Comment: try: `width:100%; max-width:600px;`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I am using top: auto; the same problem affecting there also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the solution with minor changes

**Demo** http://www.bootply.com/p6wIuR17QB

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#modest-slider {
  position: relative;
}
.slider-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="slider">

  <ul class="rslides list-unstyled" id="modest-slider" stye="position:relative;">

    <li class="slider-wrapper">

      <div class="slider-img-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=slider1" alt="slider1" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="slider-caption container">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);">
          <h1>Exclusively  New Concept!</h1>
          <p class="slider-description2">
            Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample...
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.slider-caption -->

    </li>
    <!-- /.slider-wrapper -->

  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: It is fine, but it still touching with header when I resize!!

Comment: @Santhucool It might be because of header. I might able to help you if possible to share link

Comment: Buddy I have 3 sliders and need to position boxes in different positions, Will paste the full screen code here: 1. <div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: auto; bottom: 126px; width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); height:130px;"> 2. <div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: -150px;left:570px; bottom: 126px; width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); height:130px;"> 3. <div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: 263px; bottom: 126px; width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); height:130px;">.buddy!!

Comment: @Santhucool I have removed inline css `<div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: auto; bottom: 126px; width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); height:130px;"> ` from the answer. You should build common **CSS** class for this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="row" >
<!-- changing width to 100% with 600px maximum -->
<div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: auto; bottom: 126px; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); height:130px;">
    <h1>Exclusively  New Concept!</h1>
        <p class="slider-description2">
          Lorem ipsum  sample  Lorem ipsum  sample Lorem ipsum  sample Lorem ipsum  sample Lorem ipsum  sample...
        </p>                            
</div>
```

This will not make the height change though, for that try:

```
change "height:130px;" to "height: 100%; max-height: 130px;"
```

You really need to read more about how Bootstrap works though as this is not a good way to use it

Comment: Tried, but top:auto; also creating problem!!

Comment: take it off - delete it

Comment: The box getting merged with header, please help buddy

Comment: I honestly have no idea what that means, you need to post more code

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not assign width to your div, in case you are using bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-7" style="...width: 600px...
```

Using class col-md-7 assign a particular width to your section, which is in %, so that when you resize your browser, the div resizes accordingly.
But, you overwrote the width with 600px, which is a fixed width and does not flex with browser resize.

Comment: The actual problem is that it got merged with the header when resizing!! I tried like this top=100%; max-top: -140px;

Comment: @Santhucool it's always better to post a snapshot along with your question. It will help you get quick answers. Just a suggestion do not mind.